# Animação em background HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, animação, background

gente eu vi em um site a seguinte animação no background e gostaria de saber se alguém tem o  código fonte dela ou algo do tipo ....

segue o link do site com a animação: [a link](https://apps.evozi.com/)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse background é uma animação com `canvas` (js)

Aqui tem o Github do projeto
https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/

E aqui o link dele funcionando e com opções de configuração e download
http://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/

Se vc quiser estudar o código aqui no Codepen também tem um modelo.
https://codepen.io/VincentGarreau/pen/pnlso?limit=all&page=2&q=Canvas